# Best Practices with C++ ostream (tostring)

Tags: c++, tostring, ostream

What are best practices when overloading the `<<` operator. Particularly, how do I distinguish between opearting on a pointer vs an object. Is it kosher for them to both output the same string when fed to `<<`?

For instance, consider the following code where both `Book` objects have been initialized

```
Book b1;
Book* b2;

// initialization stuff

// can both of these output the same representation of a book object?
cout << b1 << endl;
cout << b2 << endl;
```

Comment: I wouldn't.  The user may expect to see an address in the `Book*` case, and if you want to stream the pointed-to object just dereference, i.e. `cout << *b2 << endl;`

Comment: @Matt Phillips, That seems like a lot of extra dereferencing. My thinking was that since `char*` output to `<<` automatically dereferences then an object should too. Is it best practices to always dereference?

Comment: `operator<<` for `char*` does not output the same thing as for `char`. `char*` is treated specially for the special case of C strings. Note that `operator<<` will _fail_ if you give it a `char*` that is not also a C string. Bottom line; the `char*` overload is not a case for `T*` overloads in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > how do I distinguish between opearting on a pointer vs an object.

By the signature of the `operator<<` function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Book&); // operates on object
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Book*); // operates on pointer
```

> > > Is it kosher for them to both output the same string?

It is allowed, but not particularly useful. It is very rare to see the second form implemented. If you are tempted to implement the second form, realize that it is entirely redundant. For example, if you have a `Book* pBook`:

```
std::cout << *pBook << "\n";
```

That will print the object to which `pBook` points quite nicely.

Comment: I like this answer; however, I have the same question as I posted regarding @Matt Phillips comment on the main question. Why should `char*` get special treatment? (other than that it is a particularly primitive construct)

Comment: Because `char*` is not *merely* a pointer-to-char. It is also the historic text string type. If you wanted to parallel `char*`'s behavior, then your `operator<<` would need to print an array with a self-describing length of `Book`s.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overload `operator<<` for pointers-to-`T`.  Instead, overload for `T` itself (or rather, `const T&` as appropriate), and dereference the pointer in your call to `operator<<`.

```
cout << *b2 << endl;
```

Overloading for pointer-to-`T` will just create confusion and potentially name collisions, and isn't necesarry in the first place if you overload for `const T&`